# Android SQLite query not returning data after insert

Tags: android, select, sqlite, insert

I'm attempting to insert data to an SQLite database table and then immediately return the result from a select in the same call, but no data is returned.

Here is the SQL statement:

```
INSERT INTO Items (Name, DefaultExpirationIntervalId) VALUES ('Item', -1);
SELECT ItemId as '_id', Name, DefaultExpirationIntervalId FROM Items WHERE Name = 'Item';
```

Here is the code making the SQL call:

```
        Boolean isReadOnly = getSQLiteDatabase().isReadOnly();

        // Make sure we can add data to the database
        if (!isReadOnly)
        {
            // Add the item to the database and then use the result to create a new item
            Cursor cursor = getSQLiteDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);

            if (null != cursor)
            {
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                if (!cursor.isAfterLast())
                    item = new Item(cursor);
            }
        }
```

The rawQuery call returns a cursor (not null), but it is empty.

I verified through ADB that the record was inserted. I've even run this exact query through sqlite3 via the ADB shell and the item was inserted and returned as expected. I have also tried removing the select and retrieving the item in another rawQuery call and that didn't work either.

Does anybody have any idea what might be happening?
I am running this code through a unit test that creates and and destroys the database during every test run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**rawQuery** is used ONLY for **SELECT** statements.
For **INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE**, you have to use **execSQL** instead

So, first you must make an INSERT by using execSQL AND THEN use rawQuery for your SELECT.

In case you're asking why...
a SELECT is a QUERY, while INSERT, DELETE and UPDATE are COMMANDS.

Comment: Thanks a lot Klaus66!! I interpreted rawQuery as being a call that could run any script. Now I know, thanks again.

Comment: I imagined that... ;) Now, could you do a favour? Could you mark my answer as accepted? Very appreciated, thank you.